# Why my react app is so much slower than vanilla js? How to optimize it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

To better understand the question open please these two sandboxes i made. One is written with react and the other with vanilla js.

React: https://codesandbox.io/s/boxes-v2-w400we (ignore any maximum call errors, idk what they want from me lol)
Vanilla: https://codesandbox.io/s/boxes-vanilla-js-z1z26l (refresh inside browser if boxes don't show up)

The problem is that react one is very slow. And not only state change, but even class toggle. I tried to separate these functions, so it at least look fast for user, even if state change need some more time behind the scenes, but it doesn't work somehow.
On the other hand vanilla one. Yes i'm mutating object there and it's not cool, but it works almost instantly even with 10k elements!
How to achieve same speed with react? And if this is not possible, then how to at least change color fast to hide slow state changing?

So, basically i need to change this function below (from react sandbox) to something that doesn't map through whole array, finding id, copying everything just to change one item. Since we know the id already and this id match index of this item in array, why can't we just change it directly like i did in vanilla version?

```
const updateData = id => {
  setData(prevState => {
    return prevState.map(el => {
      return el.id === id ? { ...el, active: !el.active } : el;
    });
  });
};
```

I tried this, but it's still slow

```
const updateData = id => {
  setData(prevState => {
    const item = prevState[id];
    const newState = [...prevState];
    newState[id] = {...item, active: !item.active}
    return newState;
  })
}
```

Comment: you can just wrap setData in settimeout with 0 to speed up the color interaction

Comment: I don't notice any significant difference in speed on Firefox.

Comment: you can use update by index instead of map with all the indexing.

Comment: I see this improved: https://codesandbox.io/s/boxes-v2-forked-c4khgv

Comment: from a quick look - function createBoxes is called each rerender.

Comment: @SonuSindhu, this trick with timeout looks weird, but works for color. But if you'll spam click then all of these queued functions will start working and fuck things up again. Btw, your function works weird, seems like it changes state only once. Text true or false inside the boxes comes from actual state, but color just from clicks

Comment: @samuei, you mean between react and vanilla? Maybe it's just my pc or browser is slow, but for me difference is huge. Did you try to spam button? Vanilla works fast as fuck, while fucking react queuing his fucking functions